# How to use JSON data on Django View

Tags: python, django

I need to use data as JSON from an API in Django View here is my JSON data;

```
[{'Count': 5491}]
```

I need to pass just value of the "Count" key to HTML and views.py is as below;

```
def serviceReport(request):
    data = mb.post('/api/card/423/query/json')
    context = {
        'count' : data['Count']
    }
    return render(request, 'service_report.html', context)
```

I get error like this;

Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
list indices must be integers or slices, not str

What I want is to pass value of count key to service_report.html and also I want to pass multiple JSON datas like data2, data3 as data on views.py how can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using JSON in django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286192/using-json-in-django-template)

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me the full JSON but I just need value of the Count key. Besides I can get same result without SafeString just with this;
return render(request, 'service_report.html', {'data': data})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json is returning a list that contains a dict.

```
[{'Count': 5491}]
```

The brackets are the list so access that with `data[0]`

```
def serviceReport(request):
    data = mb.post('/api/card/423/query/json')
    context = {
        'count' : data[0]['Count']
    }
    return render(request, 'service_report.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

Views.py:

```
def serviceReport(request):
data = mb.post('/api/card/423/query/json')
context = {
    'data' : data
}
return render(request, 'service_report.html', context)
```

html template:
In Django you can use `{%   %}` to use Python code into html,
so you can do something like this.

```
<div>
    {% for element in data %}
        <div>{{element.data}}</div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Also if you want to check what's on your data, you could just use `{{data}}`
In anycase, i suggest you do a for in your views.py to append just the "Count" data into a list and then pass that list to the context.